# What math topic is used to solve this type of problem?

Tags: education

Assume we have available four sorting algorithms and can program in C, C++, Pascal, Fortran, and COBOL. We have available compilers that can translate from each of these to either x86 or SPARC, and we have available three different microarchitectures for x86 and three different microarchitectures for SPARC.

a. How many transformation processes are possible?

b. Write three examples of transformation processes.

c. How many transformation processes are possible if instead of three
different microarchitectures for x86 and three different microarchitectures for SPARC, there were two for x86 and four for SPARC?

Comment: This is a combinatorics problem, and is an exercise in using the [multiplication rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: It is a programming and combinatorics question: for (a) you're looking for all possible permutations, so you need to find all combinations. (b) is the time when you single out three of these combinations, (c) is another combinatorics question with more combinations possible than the first